# How to export text from annotation fields in Nuance Power PDF to Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to export some text from annotation fields in Nuance Power PDF to Excel using VBA. I added the Nuance Power PDF reference to Excel VBA (PDF Plus).

I used it and it works well but the text returned from fields is empty.

```
Set PDFApp = CreateObject("NuancePDF.App")
Set dvDoc = CreateObject("NuancePDF.DVDoc")

dvDoc.Open("\\adpdc-2\Users$\a.goudinoux\Documents\Macro Formulaire\fiche.pdf")

Set ddDoc = dvDoc.GetDDDoc()
Set ddPage = ddDoc.AcquirePage(0)
nbannots = ddPage.GetNumAnnots() - 1

For i = 0 To nbannots
    Texte = ""
    Set ddAnnot = ddPage.GetAnnot(i)
    Set ddText = ddDoc.CreateTextSelect(0, ddAnnot.GetRect())

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) = ddAnnot.GetTitle()

    For k = 0 To ddText.GetNumText()
        Texte = Texte & ddText.GetText(k)
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, i) = Texte
Next
```

Part of the PDF document : 
[image: doc]

Results : 
[image: Results]

As you can see the first line is working but not the second one.

I thought the problem was with ddText but ddText.GetNumText() gives the right number of text elements in the text selection (ex : 2, 5, 4, etc...) when I run my program in Debug Mode.
I think the problem is from the function GetText(k).

[image: GetText]

I made it work once but I can't find my code back.. 
Do you see any mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Either your annotations are more complex than indicated or you're overthinking it.

Just read the annotation with `GetContents` and call it a day.

```
Set PDFApp = CreateObject("NuancePDF.App")
Set dvDoc = CreateObject("NuancePDF.DVDoc")

dvDoc.Open("\\adpdc-2\Users$\a.goudinoux\Documents\Macro Formulaire\fiche.pdf")

Set ddDoc = dvDoc.GetDDDoc()
Set ddPage = ddDoc.AcquirePage(0)
nbannots = ddPage.GetNumAnnots() - 1

For i = 0 To nbannots
    Set ddAnnot = ddPage.GetAnnot(i)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) = ddAnnot.GetTitle
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, i) = ddAnnot.GetContents

Next i
```